# I'm trying to add an image randomizer to a wix strip. I need to edit the code but don't know how

Tags: velo

I contacted Wix to ask if it was possible to add an image randomizer to a strip. They gave me a set of code I can add to the website to do this. I don't exactly know how to edit it to fit the website and make it work.
The code I was given is:

```
import wixWindow from 'wix-window';
import wixData from 'wix-data';

$w.onReady(async function () {

    // Check the render env so this is just done once.
    // Otherwise, server-side will render, and then the image
    // switches to the image that the client-side rendered.
    if (wixWindow.rendering.env === 'browser' || wixWindow.viewMode === 'Preview') {
        let res = await wixData.query("HomepageImages").find();
        let items = res.items;
        let count = items.length;   // how many images do we have?
        let rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
        $w('#image1').src = items[rnd].image;   // get a random image
        $w('#image1').show(); // image on page is hidden, we we now show it
    }
});
```

Also, is there a way to connect one strip with another one so that a particular image will always trigger a 'partner' image inside the other strip? The initial strip would be the random image which triggers a specific other image in the other strip. If that makes sense!

Comment: `I don't exactly know how to edit it to fit the website and make it work` What doesn't fit now?

Comment: I don't know how to integrate it. This might be a better way to word it. I know where I have to fill it in but I don't know how to customize it to make it work once I integrated it.

Comment: Since it's not a general question, Stackoverflow is not the right place because other people can't benefit fromvyhe answer. I can try to help out of here, find my contact details in my profile page.